# Minecraft modding error: cannot find symbol class & cannot find variable class

Tags: minecraft-forge

I've been trying to run my Minecraft mod, but I keep getting 2 errors that say 'cannot find symbol class' and 'cannot find variable class' and I have no idea what they mean. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse Temurin if that helps. I've used tutorials by Modding by Kaupenjoe. Please tell me if you need anymore detail. My mod is also a Forge mod.

```
'Cannot find symbol class':
error: cannot find symbol
import net.tatambolina.tatambolinasfoodandrecipesmod.TatambolinasFoodAndRecipesMod;
^
symbol:   class TatambolinasFoodAndRecipesMod
location: package net.tatambolina.tatambolinasfoodandrecipesmod

'Cannot find variable class':
error: cannot find symbol
DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.ITEMS, TatambolinasFoodAndRecipesMod.MOD_ID);
^
symbol:   variable TatambolinasFoodAndRecipesMod
location: class ModItems
```